# Exclude headers from calculation

Tags: excel, vba

The following code has a problem with calculation.

This calculation finds out the % of rows filled per column. However because of the headers, when a sheet has no values in the columns but has headers it shows as 50%, which isn't correct. 
Is there any way to alter this so It doesn't include headers in the calculation? Would this be the best work around?

```
Sub Stackage()
'added function to skip corrupt files works! Adding skipped files works.. and do something about 50%.
'changed lrw to long, doesnt skip those files now :)



Dim wb As Workbook, fileNames As Object, errCheck As Boolean 'part of loop


Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim resultSheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim lco As Integer
Dim lrw As Long
Dim resultRow As Integer
Dim measurement As Double

'To compile skipped files
Dim wksSkipped As Worksheet
Set wksSkipped = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Skipped")


Set resultSheet = Application.ActiveSheet
resultRow = 1

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'get user input for files to search
  Set fileNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  errCheck = UserInput.FileDialogDictionary(fileNames)
  If errCheck Then Exit Sub


For Each Key In fileNames 'loop through the dictionary
On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileNames(Key))
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wb = Nothing    ' or set a boolean error flag
End If
On Error GoTo 0    ' or custom error handler

If wb Is Nothing Then
wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = fileNames(Key)
Else
    Debug.Print "Successfully loaded " & fileNames(Key)
    wb.Application.Visible = False 'make it not visible


    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Cells) = 0 Then
            'define the range to measure
            lco = ws.Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious, False).Column
            lrw = ws.Columns("A:Y").Find("*", , xlValues, , xlRows, xlPrevious).Row
            If lrw = 1 Then lrw = 2
            For i = 1 To lco
                measurement = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, i), ws.Cells(lrw, i))) / lrw
                resultSheet.Cells(resultRow, 1).Value = wb.Name
                resultSheet.Cells(resultRow, 2).Value = ws.Name
                resultSheet.Cells(resultRow, 3).Value = ws.Cells(1, i).Value
                resultSheet.Cells(resultRow, 4).Style = "Percent"
                resultSheet.Cells(resultRow, 5).Value = measurement
                resultRow = resultRow + 1
            Next
        End If
    Next
    wb.Application.Visible = True '' I added
    wb.Close savechanges:=False 'close the workbook do not save
    Set wb = Nothing 'release the object
    End If
Next 'End of the fileNames loop

Set fileNames = Nothing
'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make one small change to this line:

```
measurement = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, i), ws.Cells(lrw, i))) / lrw
```

Change it to this:

```
measurement = ws.Evaluate("sumproduct((" & ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, i), ws.Cells(lrw, i)).Address & "<>"""")+0)") / (lrw - 1)
```

Comment: Not sure if this excludes it from calculation

Comment: If the header is row 1, then it is excluded. Is the header a different row?

Comment: For example, 4 rows(3 beneath header) are there, and then 1 is the header, shows as 75%.

Comment: I updated the answer. Please look at the very end of the line of code to change to.

Comment: It works well, but for some reason on some of the calculations I get 99 on columns where nothing is there.

Comment: Could there be formulas there that are returning a blank? The reason I ask is because CountA() will count those.

Comment: Ah good point, do you know how I could change that in my current code? The calculations work mostly, but for some reason i get that a percent on some where it should be 0.

Comment: So the task is to count the cells in the column that have a value length greater than zero?

Comment: Not exactly, it loops through directory, goes through each worksheet of each files,  counts how much % of the rows are filled for each column. (amount of rows filled that column / last row #). Ex: if 5 rows are filled out of 10(10 is determined by the longest row aka the last row), it would be 50%.

Comment: Yes, all that was clear already. You said it mostly worked and that it was a good point that the method (CountA()) you are using to count the rows to include in the average includes formula results that are blank in the count. You then asked if I know how to change that. I DO. But I was trying to confirm that what you want changed is a way of doing what CountA() is doing but to also ignore blanks returned from formulas. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Yes I want that changed,  I confirm that. Because if it doesnt count blanks, those columns will properly be stated at 0% i believe.

Comment: Yes I want to count the cells in the column that have values (either text or number). Sorry I didnt answer it.

Comment: OK. I updated my answer again. Please take a look and see if that works.

Comment: Fixed my initial issues, but when column contains #'s, but text it works fine. it kind of messed up, when should be 100% it will have 0.

Comment: I'm sorry that was not clear. Can you state the current problem again please?

Comment: I mean that when there are numbers only in a column it doesn't calculate properly. Text values seems to work perfect .

Comment: OK. I updated again. Please have a look and let me know.

Comment: No, last time was more accurate. This is abit wild in the numbers returned as I might get 1.33 whereas before I got alot of accuracy, but not when it came to #'s in columns

Comment: That's embarassing. I accidentally posted my test code and forgot to change it to your variables. I fixed that now. PLEASE TRY AGAIN and sorry.

Comment: I get this error `measurement = ws.Evaluate("sumproduct((" & ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, i), ws.Cells(lrw, i)).Address & "<>"""")+0)") / (lrw - 1)` mismatch. hm let me try again., even though it has an error, it seems to have stopped at a workbook

Comment: This could be  a workbook issue, it stops at a certain one, could it be the workbook format? I can open it fine. Mismatch type 13

Comment: OK. Progress. For the workbook that is failing, do other columns work or does the first column attempted fail?

Comment: Yes Progres indeed :D . Yes, if i do the workbook on its own the first sheet actually shows proper results, then halfway through the second sheet the process fails :(

Comment: Yes sure, but i will delete some info.

Comment: Sent it danny, I only sent the sheet. Not full book. And other then that, it is exactly as is.

Comment: OK. I ran the code on that worksheet and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks Danny. Im not really sure why it wont pass that workbook. i'll keep trying.

Comment: Found out the problem, there was a #N/A in a random cell all the way down the sheet.

Comment: Beautiful. Well, at least you can move forward without this gnawing at you!

Comment: Is there a way to ignore all #N/A in sheets? I guess manually ill have to do it.